# Why bd-navbar not exist in bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, documentation

I'm trying to create a page documentation as bootstrap's documentation and when I was study I saw that there are many classes inside divs like bd-navbar and others that starts with "bd-" that there aren't in css's bootstrap.

Where are these classes?

Answer (score 1):

They are not in bootstrap.css, they are in the Bootstrap website's doc.css file.

Answer (score 0):

The bd-navbar class provides the position: sticky attribute.
Instead of the class `bd-navbar` you can use the class `sticky-top`.

This class is present in all the versions of bootstrap 4.x
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/#placement.

As you see in the documentation `.sticky-top` uses `position: sticky`, which isn’t fully supported in every browser.

Personally I think that if you don't want to provide support for Internet Explorer 11 you can use it.
Internet explorer 11 End of life is officially set to August 17th, 2021.

Otherwise if you want to fully support every browser you should use the class fixed-top for your navbar.